# Cross platform Bluetooth application using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, mobile, bluetooth, cross-platform

I am a newbie for mobile application development. In my organization, they've assigned me a task to develop a cross platform application.

We have build our own hardware for Bluetooth which contains classic Bluetooth for android and Bluetooth low energy (BLE) for ios. this hardware will communicate to another hardware which contains some sensors to calculate biological things.

Now I need to develop a cross platform application which can send & receive command from Bluetooth hardware. So for this I chose AngularJS and for Bluetooth plugin ng-cordova. now please tell me how to move further, how should I create an application without using phonegap or appery. if it is compulsory to use one of them which one I should prefer? Please let me know if any other option available.

**If possible please provide me some useful links for sample application.**

My question may be silly, please don't hurt me.